# setInterval() inside express router.use() not correct

Tags: node.js, setinterval

I'm using `setInterval()` inside a node.js express route with `router.use()`, but after a short time, the interval starts to jump. It looks like it's been triggered more than once after some period. What can be wrong?

```
const router = express.Router();

router.use( (req, res, next) => {

  // Wrong logging, starts to jump after some time
  setInterval(update, 5000, "Updating inside router.use()...");
  next();

});

function update(message) {
  console.log(message, new Date())
}

// Correct logging (every 5 seconds)
setInterval(update, 5000, "Updating...");
```

This is the output:

```
Updating... 2022-02-24T21:50:41.545Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:50:46.025Z
Updating... 2022-02-24T21:50:46.545Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:50:51.026Z
Updating... 2022-02-24T21:50:51.546Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:50:56.027Z
Updating... 2022-02-24T21:50:56.547Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:50:58.155Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:51:01.028Z
Updating... 2022-02-24T21:51:01.548Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:51:03.156Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:51:06.028Z
Updating... 2022-02-24T21:51:06.549Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:51:08.156Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:51:10.339Z
Updating inside router.use()... 2022-02-24T21:51:11.030Z
```

I simplified my router.use() example overhere, but I need the setInterval() to work inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a `setInterval()` inside of a `router.use()` will start a new separate interval timer for every incoming request that hits this router.  After two requests, you'll have two separate interval timers.  After three requests, you'll have three separate interval timers and they will just continue to pile up forever - all running at the same time.  So, the interval isn't jumping, you're just getting multiple interval timers overlapping and you're seeing the combined results of multiple timers running at once, each started at different times.

This cannot be the proper design.

Keep in mind that these timers run on behalf of the whole server, not just one user or one request.  Once you start an interval timer, it keeps going forever until you call `clearInterval(timerId)` on it.

You don't describe the actual design problem here (what problem you're trying to solve with the timers) so we can't really help with a suggested design.  Most likely, you only want one timer, ever.  Ideally, you wouldn't poll anything and would find a more event-driven design.

Comment: Clear answer. My real problem is that I want to access `req.app`, in order to access my socket.io object `app.get('socketio')` to update clients with values coming from an external REST api. But as you stated, this is no proper design, I'll look for another way to access my socket.io object.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden - `io.emit(...)` will send to all currently connected sockets if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes I know, that is what I tried: `const io = app.get('socketio'); io.emit(...)`, but inside the router.use()

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden - Put it outside of any route.  Start the interval timer once when your server starts.  That should be sufficient.  It will broadcast to any connected socket.io clients on each timer interval and there will be one and only one timer running.